# Style each section of a date after it been formatted with the correct date format

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, styles

My problem is styling a date object properly. I would like to style the day month year and sometimes day of the week. If the date object is static it would be simple. The date format is passed in and usually takes in the account of localization so I don't know what the format will look like. I could be given mm/dd/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy (Simple case). Currently, we just pass it through angular date filter and it produces the correct date, but I can't style the month to be bold and blue for example.

Is there an easy way to parse a date with the format of dd/mm/yyyy and gives me:"12/12/1988"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular ships with a `Date` filter.

`<p>{{'1491941202157' | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>` => 11/04/2017

Pair that up with a directive using the `$filter` in the controller, or simply split the string on `/` and wrap in style-able nodes like `<span>`, for example.

More here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if the format passed in is mmddyyyy, what would be my split then?

Comment: Ah, we can control the format a little. Your answer works perfectly. Thank you for solution.

Comment: My pleasure, Happy to help!